Should we use subject auxiliary verb order in 'what a better day could there be to go to one of the local farmers markets!'?
This is from TwoMadExplorers at 0:21:

hey today is a Sunday by the way and what a better day could there be
to go to one of the local farmers markets!

Two points to ask:

From the context, the sentence should belong to exclamatory sentence, so the subject auxiliary verb order should be used but there is a subject–auxiliary inversion, is it right?
Although this is an exclamatory sentence, should we use 'good' instead of 'better'?


There is no 'a' - she says What better day could there be? this is an established usage which means What day could be better than a Sunday to go to a farmers' market? - that is, in her opinion Sunday is the best day to go there. It's a 'rhetorical question' - one that is asked to make a point, not because an answer is required.

Seems a bit convoluted.  I would just say - It's Sunday, a perfect "(or great)" day to visit one of the local farmers' markets.

It is convoluted, because it's a matter of oratorical style, not basic English usage.

It may seem 'convoluted' to Eric, but it certainly isn't 'oratorical' - the girl in the video is using ordinary conversational language. Expressions like What better way to start the day than... are commonplace.

"convoluted" here because the version in the original question is atypically wordy ("could there be to go" and "to one of the local"). Typically the exclamation would be succinct and general: "What better day than Sunday to go to a farmers market!".
